# Which is stable version of hibernate that we can use for Java web application

Tags: hibernate

We want to use Hibernate in our Java base web application , but we are not sure which stable version of Hibernate should we use ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That'll depend on your JVM version, app server version etc., but a good place to start is [Hibernate.org](http://www.hibernate.org/) and the [latest Hibernate](http://sourceforge.net/projects/hibernate/files/latest/download) download bundles.

Comment: I assume this was downvoted since the above contained a link to a now superseded version of Hibernate. A comment to that effect may be a nicer means of communicating this